# How do I reverse a 32 bit register in riscV (32 bit), is there a command for it?

Tags: assembly, riscv, riscv32

I am using the venus simulator for writing code. I can't find a specific instruction for rotation or reversing a register.

Comment: bit-reverse (like ARM rbit) or endian byte-reverse (like x86 bswap)?  Extension B might have endian swap, but IIRC baseline RISC-V doesn't have either.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/wvSybu

Comment: similar to rbit in ARM

Comment: @PeterCordes, technically, the 2 questions are similar but not duplicates. I mean the other is about byte swapping and this one is about bit-reversing.

Comment: @maxschlepzig: since the OP didn't specify, I had to guess.   Apparently I guessed wrong, but questions lacking sufficient info to be answered should be closed anyway; duphammer to a question that *might* be what someone is looking for achieves the goal of closing the question.  Either way I was pretty sure the key detail was going to be Extension B, so again that covers it.  Thanks for answering [Convert between big-endian and little-endian on RISC-V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60680989) that covers both rev and rev8